# Kubernetes v1.11.1 too many connection from Kube-api to node kubelet

Tags: kubernetes

I have kubernetes 1.11 cluster with 26 nodes and 3 master all servers running on Centos 7 OS, its running for a while. recently I noticed kube-api server establishing too many connection to node kubelet port `10250`. today its used all the ports on the primary master, helm command started failing. I have restart some nodes to clean up the ports

```
tcp        0      0 xx.xx.xx3.53:50863     xx.xx.xx4.94:10250     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 xx.xx.xx3.53:60531     xx.xx.xx3.62:10250     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 xx.xx.xx3.53:42625     xx.xx.xx3.63:10250     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 xx.xx.xx3.53:56703     xx.xx.xx3.61:10250     ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 xx.xx.xx3.53:49426     xx.xx.xx3.64:10250     ESTABLISHED
```

all the nodes it used 50 thousand ports

```
netstat -an |grep -ci estab
51163
```

I like to know why kube-api creating too many connection to kubelet. how to resolve this issue.

Thanks
SR

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/67382

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As spotted by @Ijaz Ahmad Khan, it's a known issue affecting v1.11.1, reported already as bug on github under the bug report [#67382](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/67382). From what I can see it`s already fixed in upper Kubernetes releases.

Comment: I will upgrade my cluster to v1.11.5 and update this post. Thanks

Comment: upgrade fixed my issue